# Rewrite url, replace variable with keyword

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following URL's:

```
http://www.website.com/index.php?page=boat&id=1&lang=nl
```

index.php is my main file. The variable "page=" is used to show the right page.

I came up with the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*) /index.php?lang=$1&keyword=$2&page=$3&id=$3&model=$4 [L]
```

which changes the url to:

```
http://www.website.com/nl/yachts-for-sale/boat/1/princess-50
```

However I want the url to look like:

```
http://www.website.com/nl/yachts-for-sale/1/princess-50
```

As you can see without "boat" in the url. But this is an important variable because it decides which page to show.

How can I achieve this? The "yachts-for-sale" keyword is exclusive for the "boat" page. I was thinking about a Rewritemap, but that is not allowed in a .htaccess file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You state that

> The "yachts-for-sale" keyword is exclusive for the "boat" page

If you do not have that rule in your PHP, add it in your rewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(yachts-for-sale)/([^/]*)/([^/]*) /index.php?lang=$1&keyword=$2&page=boat&id=$3&model=$4 [L]
```

Comment: No problem, could you mark my answer as the correct one? That way future users will know what to do and i get some bacon for helping you ;)